# pgrep in bash script not working correctly

Tags: bash, shell

Here is the piece of code from shell script that is causing the problem.

```
LOG_FILE="/home/sample.log"
PID_FILE="/home/sample.pid" 
sudo -u user1 trinidad -e production > "$LOG_FILE" 2>&1 & echo $! > "$PID_FILE"

PARENT_PID=`cat "$PID_FILE"`
pgrep -P "$PARENT_PID" > "$PID_FILE"
```

But here the last command does not print anything to PID_FILE. So for debugging purpose I tried echoing `echo $PARENT_PID`. It correctly prints the output like 1234.

Also in shell script If I do `pgrep -P 1234` then also it prints the child process correctly but only if I do `pgrep -P $PARENT_PID` then it prints nothing.

Answer (score 0):

You are writing stuff into a file and then reading the file back in.  While that is just wasteful, not actually an explanation of your problem, I would refactor to

```
LOG_FILE="/home/sample.log"
PID_FILE="/home/sample.pid" 
sudo -u user1 trinidad -e production > "$LOG_FILE" 2>&1 &
PARENT_PID=$!
pgrep -P "$PARENT_PID" > "$PID_FILE"
```

I'm guessing your actual problem is that the `sudo` process doesn't spawn any children.  The action of `pgrep -P` is to print processes which are children of the PID you specify; if your process doesn't spawn any children, it won't print any.

Comment: Also you were storing the parent PID in the file, then immediately overwriting it with the output from `pgrep`.  Was that on purpose?  I took out the writing of the parent PID to the file, which was being overwritten anyway.

Comment: Actually there are two process that gets spawned. $! returns the parent process. That parent process has one child process. So basically later when server needs to be stopped that time I need child process so that I can kill it. I hope it explains things

Comment: Why don't you kill the parent?  You are going to need to wait for the parent anyway, so it makes sense to just store its PID directly and kill it.  That also avoids the possibility that the child has not yet been spawned when you attempt to find its PID.

Comment: well I tried killing the parent but child process stays as it is. Anyway I have changed this code. So its not a issue anymore